# Uploading files to artifactory from Java

Tags: java, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I have a handful of files in Local which I want to deploy to artifactory. 
I am planning to create a java class which connects to the repository , create folders & then upload the files inside the folder.

Is it possible to do this in Java ? Please suggest me if you are aware of anyother alternatives.

P.S: Communication between local & artificatory is disabled so were not using gradle to upload files to artifactory thus seeking alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use the Artifactory [REST Client Java](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-client-java) API bindings which provides Artifactory connection and management within your Java code.
The other option is using the [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli/) - a compact client that provides a simple interface that automates access to JFrog products (including Artifactory).

Comment: The REST Client doesn't seem to be very comprehensive. From the documentation I could not figure out the request URL for operations like creating repo, creating folders inside repo etc. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [HttpUrlConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to make put request to your artifactory instance. Artifactory creates directory structure for you based on the file path you mention. If you want your file to be at https://artifactory.company.com/prod-repo/projA/build10/rhel7/artifact.rpm. You can make a PUT request and Artifactory will create `projA/build10/rhel7/` directory structure and deploy file in there, if the path doesn't exist. NOTE that repo (prod-repo) should exist. If you can access your artifactory instance through browser then you will have access to REST API too and thats all you need to perform the action. If not [SCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) files to jump-server/Vm where can reach artifactory and run your code from there.